# How can I access the spring model object in Ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to access a specific end point through Ajax get. In the success I do want to handle some logic conditionally using the "statusCode" that was set in the model. 
below is my code, 
Controller code:

```
 @RequestMapping("/person")
    public String loginError(Model model) {
        String code = "active"
        model.addAttribute("statusCode", code)
        return "person";
    }
```

JS code:

```
 $.ajax(url, {
         success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                 //I want to access the statusCode here 
             },
         error: function() {
            console.log("Error");
         }
      });
```

In the data abject I do get the person html returned. But I want to know how can I access the statusCode inside the success block? 
Thank you.

Comment: if your endpoint is returning HTML, then you'd have to parse the HTML to find any information from it. If you want to get actual data values in the JavaScript then you need to create an endpoint which returns JSON instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an AJAX call and you need to handle the status code response, you need to say in yout controller the response is an AJAX type rather an ModelAndView. Use this annotation **ResponseBody**

```
@RequestMapping("/person")
@ResponseBody
public String loginError(Model model) {
    String code = "active"
    //Here add your logic and returs the String or Object to handle in the JS code
    return code;
}
```

Personally i would use a more complete Bean response, something like:

```
class JsonResponse implements Serializable {
    @Getter @Setter
    private int code;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String message;

    @Getter @Setter
    private int action;

    //Any other attributes useful for your logic 

}
```